# How to modify HTML based on viewport in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, viewport

I am using React and I am trying to modify the content of a component based on the viewport of the device.
The solution I came up with is to wrap in 2 separate divs the content for mobile and the content for desktop, and then to use CSS "display:none" and appropriate breakpoints to display either one div or the other one. I am sure there is a better and more efficient solution, but I can't find it.

Comment: You can use CSS media query for different viewports.

Answer (score 0):

I much easier way would be to use media queries. These allow you to basically alter your CSS based on the size of the browser/device and as the size changes you can decide how your page looks by adding CSS within the media queries.

Take a look at this site for further clarity:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp